# How to dump file data into AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: aws-elasticsearch

I have a large json text file (line terminated json documents generated by querying `DynamoDB` on based on a filter criteria). What is the best way to index these documents into `AWS` managed `ElasticSearch` service.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in from of a local file or in EC2, you can consider using Logstash.

The open source version of Logstash (Logstash OSS) provides a convenient way to use the bulk API to upload data into your Amazon Elasticsearch Service (Amazon ES) domain.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-logstash.html

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I'm pretty new to Logstash, can you provide Java code samples for bulk upload using Logstash.